# Selecting feature by attribute with expression to delete it from same feature class in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, delete

I want to create a model in ModelBuilder that contain two processes:

- The first  process is to select a feature using an expression.
- The second process is to delete the feature selected in first process.

I want to do both processes within the same feature Class, so I cannot use the Select (Analysis) tool because that gives me a new feature class as output.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

I found the Select Layer By Attributes tool but it does not accept feature class format, and I do not have any other format except feature class.

Answer (score 3):

If the model is outside of ArcMap you will first have to use [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) tool, then you may use [Select Layer by Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000) tool followed by the [Delete Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000036000000) tool.

Comment: thank you man ..
but I can't convert Feature Class to Feature layer because I want to use the Same feature Class many time ..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you cannot re-use the feature layer many times, can you expand more on this?

Comment: because my feature class must be inside file GeoDB, and I think the GeoDB do not accept feature layer . Is it right ?
Also the features inside feature class is change several time per day .

Comment: The feature layer is not a new layer that is saved to the GeoDB, only a in-memory layer.  Once you have the in-memory selection you should be able to delete those related features that are selected (for the feature class).

Answer (score 1):

Prior to you adding another requirement for this to be done totally within the original feature class, it seemed possible to do this in a single step using the Select (Analysis) tool that works directly on a feature class.

If you were planning to Select By Attribute where Field = 'X' and then delete the selected records, simply use Select (Analysis) to select records where Field <> 'X' instead.

Comment: Thank you man for replay >
but the Select ( analysis ) tool do not give me expression to select some of feature inside feature class ..

Comment: I think you must be looking at a different tool - Select (Analysis) accepts an SQL expression.

Comment: sorry man .. You are right ..
the problem with Select ( analysis ) tool is give me different layer in output

Comment: I think you should edit your question to be more explicit about your requirements.